# Multiple new variable in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is simple, I'm using the query

```
(ReturnItm.PackQty * ReturnItm.ReturnQty) as Total_Qty,

CASE 
  WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='U' THEN 
    IF(Inventory.Price=0,Inventory.Pricec,Inventory.Price)
  WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='P' THEN Inventory.Pricep
  ELSE Inventory.Pricec
END AS Price
```

So, how to multiple that Total_Qty and Price?

Is it just like this?

```
(Total_Qty*Price) as Total_price
```

Help me, please

Comment: This is the original problem

I want to multiple Total_Qty with Price
======================
(ReturnItm.PackQty * ReturnItm.ReturnQty) as Total_Qty,
CASE 
WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='U' THEN IF(Inventory.Price=0,Inventory.Pricec,Inventory.Price)
WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='P' THEN Inventory.Pricep
ELSE Inventory.Pricec
END AS Price

Comment: @yusof - edit your question and add that information there. Where you can comment it as multi-line code. Comments are not the right place for adding code.

Comment: @MatBailie sure thanks

Answer (score 0):

To select this product in the same select clause, you'll have to repeat the full expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    Test.1,
    Test.2,
    Test.3,
    Test.4,
    (Test.1 * Test.2) AS TestNew1,
    (Test.3 * Test.4) AS TestNew2,
    Test.1 * Test.2 * Test.3 * Test.4 AS TotalTest
FROM Test;
```

Comment: This is the original problem

I want to multiple Total_Qty with Price
======================
(ReturnItm.PackQty * ReturnItm.ReturnQty) as Total_Qty,
CASE 
WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='U' THEN IF(Inventory.Price=0,Inventory.Pricec,Inventory.Price)
WHEN ReturnItm.UOM='P' THEN Inventory.Pricep
ELSE Inventory.Pricec
END AS Price

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query...

```
SELECT
  *,
  (TestNew1 * TestNew2) as TotalTest
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Test.1,
    Test.2,
    Test.3,
    Test.4,
    (Test.1 * Test.2) as TestNew1,
    (Test.3 * Test.4) as TestNew2
  FROM
    Test
)
  AS x
```

The inner query acts as a scope within which the new columns can be expressed, and the outer query acts as a scope where there can be referrenced.

Also, in terms of performance, note that SQL isn't executed as written. It's a "declarative" language; it's a means of expressing the functionality, and then the DBMS turns than in to an actual execution plan.